# Add items to select field form - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I have a form with a select field followed by an add button. When the user clicks add I want whatever item is selected to be added to an array so I can pass it in my form

// this is my visible field

```
<select id="contactsFollow" name="contactsFollow">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select> 
<button type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
```

What would be the best way for me to go about doing this? I am assuming jquery will do this but I have no clue on how to implement.

Comment: need to explain further.. just adding the option won't make it selected unless you want it selected right away. Expect multiple additions? Can also do it without the button when user changes the visible select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what are you tryin to do .. but adding it to a select and passing it in a form make no sense to me since u need to select the hidden selectbox again to pass it to a form... anyways jquery is the best option to me..

and here is how you can do it..

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  $('#contactsFollow :selected').appendTo('#contactsFollowSelected');
});
```

---

**UPDATED**

make hidden input field..

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedoption" id="selectedoption" value="" />
```

**jquery**

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
   var selected=$('#contactsFollow :selected').val();
   var hiddeninputValue=$('#selectedoption').val();
   if(hiddeninputValue==""){
      $('#selectedoption').val(selected);
   }else{
      $('#selectedoption').val(hiddeninputValue + ',' + selected);
   }
   $('#contactsFollow :selected').remove();
});
```

seperate the hidden value with ',' before inserting it to db..

example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsNKR/1/)

Comment: Good point. Too early here! My original select field has several options and I need the options that the user selects and hits add to be added to an array that I can pass in my form to be inserted into the db.

Comment: in that case u can use hidden input.. with comma seperated values.. i think that will be easy.. later you can seperate the comma and insert it into db.. ok hang on i will post some example..

Comment: updated my answer..check it out... and example fiddle too .. to make sure values in hidden field is correct

Comment: Thanks works great. Two things though I noticed. 1) It automatically adds the default value even if the add button is never clicked. So if I just open the form and hit submit it is like the defualt select value was added. 2) Is there a way to make the added options disappear from the select field?

Comment: I think that the first issue is because the submit is a 'btn' object too maybe I should put an id on the add button.. and somehow specify that ID in the function

Comment: and for your second issue u can use `$('#contactsFollow :selected').remove();` and the end of click function.. updated my ans

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MsNKR/

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  $('#contactsFollow :selected').appendTo('#contactsFollowSelected');
});
```

or Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zvQgq/ if you don't want to remove options from first select

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  $('#contactsFollow :selected').clone().appendTo('#contactsFollowSelected');
});
```